Accessing service inside container using host networking from another container
I have a docker container A which must run with network_mode: "host", and exposes a service at port 13557.
I also have ufw which by default blocks all ports not explicitly allow-listed, including requests made to host.docker.internal:13557.
How can my other containers within the same compose project but not using network_mode: "host" reach the service at A:13557?
Some solutions suggest adding a ufw rule to allow outbound traffic using the docker0 interface:
ufw allow out on docker0 from 172.17.0.0/16
ufw allow out on docker0 from 172.17.0.0/16 port 80 proto tcp

However, on my system, the docker0 interface appears to be down and instead there appear to be a specific bridge interface for each compose project:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
...
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
...
14: br-29967e9cbcae: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
15: br-b835b6056915: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
16: br-c9eb279cb864: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
17: br-653e48e09916: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
18: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
...

Each bridge has its own network mask, so it's not clear how to create the ufw allow rule.
I see that docker network provides details about network addresses and other details for containers not in host networking mode, but these network masks can change from one host to another.
In another similar post a solution like below is provided:
ufw allow from 172.22.0.0/16 to 172.17.0.1

But the 172.22.0.0/16 network is specific to a given container and this may change with a restart or by switching to another host. Also this appears to provide access from all of the containers in that network to all of the host services.
Is it possible within the docker framework to programmatically allow non-host-networking containers to access a specific service like A:13557 provided by a container in host networking mode? Is it possible for the host-networking container to identify the non-host-networking network and bind to ports on it?

If you can fix service A so it uses Docker networking, that's better.  Otherwise, since it disables Docker networking, it's indistinguishable from another process running directly on the host, and the techniques in From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine? might work.  Can you explain why service A needs to disable Docker's networking stack?  (Is there a programming question here?)

The service listens to dhcp requests on the local LAN and makes that information available to other containers via HTTP.

I guess that nothing is stopping the host-networking container to bind on an the interface used by other containers. Except that I'm not sure if there is a way to determine the subnet mask of the other containers from within the host-networking container.

It occurred to me that I could have the http server listen on a unix socket and then mount-bind that socket onto the necessary containers. This would remove the need to modify the firewall while still allowing access to the service from a specific container.

I resolved this issue nicely by using unix sockets on a shared volume.
The service running on the host-networking container listens on a unix socket inside a volume A, and the same volume A is mounted on the other containers that require access to the service.
Example:
volumes:
  ...
  service-socket:
services:
  service-A:
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - service-socket:/var/run/service-A
    environment:
        - SERVICE_SOCKET=/var/run/service-A/service.sock
  service-B:
    volumes:
      - service-socket:/var/run/service-A
    environment:
        - SERVICE_SOCKET=/var/run/service-A/service.sock

